# Parsing unique values in a CSV where the primary key is not unique

Tags: python, parsing, csv

This seems pretty trivial. Generally, I'd do something like the following:

```
results = []
reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
for line in reader:  # iterate over the lines in the csv
    if line[1] in ['XXX','YYY','ZZZ']:  # check if the 2nd element is one you're looking for
        results.append(line)    # if so, add this line the the results list
```

However, my data set isn't so simply formatted. It looks like the following:

```
Symbol,Values Date
XXX,8/2/2010
XXX,8/3/2010
XXX,8/4/2010
YYY,8/2/2010
YYY,8/3/2010
YYY,8/4/2010
ZZZ,8/2/2010
ZZZ,8/3/2010
ZZZ,8/4/2010
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is parse the first date for each unique Symbol in the list such that I end up with the following:

```
XXX,8/2/2010
YYY,8/2/2010
ZZZ,8/2/2010
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) may help. ;-)

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv('file.csv').groupby('Symbol').first()
```

Comment: That would do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using a set of already found 1st element:

```
results = []
reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
already_done = set()
for line in reader:  # iterate over the lines in the csv
    if line[1] in ['XXX','YYY','ZZZ'] and line[0] not in already_done:
        results.append(line)    # if so, add this line the the results list
        already_done.add(line[0])
```